# Unwanted mouse activity during mousedown on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, keylogger

If this is not the appropriate community for this, let me know and move this.

Starting a couple months ago, when I click left mouse button and hold it down, almost immediately extra activity takes place that interrupts my action.  For example if I am highlighting a region in a spreadsheet. First thing I did was try a new mouse, but the unwanted activity continues. I've run virus scans, rootkit revealer, these come up clean.

From what I barely remember about Windows API, something would have to be hooking into the events for mouse to receive messages, then running its own actions. How can I determine IF something has hooked into mouse events, and what process and executable is responsible?

I strongly suspect some type of keylogger.

Comment: It’s not a key logger

Comment: 1) Do you have any utility such as AutoHotkey or XMouseButton? 2) Look in Task Manager, Details, to see what is using CPU time when you click the mouse button.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No. CPU time is normal whether holding down mouse button or not. What is interesting though is with taskmgr running, I cannot invoke the behavior. I'll do some experimentation but something may be detecting the taskmgr and laying low. Immediately upon closing Taskmgr, the behavior resumes.

Comment: The last observation is no longer true. Leaving taskmgr running the behavior returns in a few minutes.